# R algorithm to find typing error and replace with correct string

Tags: r, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a dataset that has multiple columns of data.
however there are 3 columns of interest with data like the below (note there are thousands of rows here)

| Year | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | a | x |
| 2016 | a | x |
| **2017** | **b** | x |
| 2018 | a | x |
| 2019 | a | x |
| 2020 | a | x |
| 2015 | S | y |
| **2016** | **S** | y |
| **2016** | **T** | y |
| 2017 | S | y |
| 2018 | S | y |
| 2019 | S | y |
| 2020 | S | y |

So basically where I have a **b** that should be an **a** in the year but there are no other **x** in that year then it needs to update.
But also I **don't** want the **T** to update as there is already a **S** in the same year.

any help on this would be appreciated here

Comment: How do you determine the replacement? Is there a fixed set or order of options to pick from?

Comment: sorry realized that I had X in all rows when there should have been a y there for the 2nd grouping

Comment: So should model "x" only include makes "a" and "b", and model "y" only include makes "S" and "T"?

Comment: But model ‘x’ should only include  ‘a’. The reason is that that the ‘b’ only appears by itself in a year where as the S & T are in the same year